# Show locations near user's location

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm developing an app and I'm trying to implement a means of listing stores close to the user's current location using the android mapbox SDK. Can anyone give a help how can I implement this?

Comment: Kindly use Google search for such broad questions. Post problem/code specific questions here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [the Mapbox Tilequery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/interactive-tools/tilequery-api-playground/) to query `Point`s in the `building` layer of the Mapbox Streets style. Check the `type` property for each `Feature` that is in the API response's `FeatureCollection`. Check that the `type` is a store, rather than coffee shops, salons, etc. Use the `LocationComponent`'s `getLastKnownLocation` as the query coordinate.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/tilequery

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location

If you want to listen to device location changes: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/

Or you could query rendered `Feature`s on a specific layer:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/query/

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=queryRenderedFeatures&type=

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/BasicSymbolLayerActivity.java

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/count-features-in-a-selected-area/

Answer (score 0):

you should calculate the distance between the user position and store position , you can do this using this method :

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2)) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
        return (dist);
    }
}
```